# Is there any easy way to create bootstrap layout?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Trying to build a SPA, Need to create a customized screens.I have tried some online tools for building bootstrap layout.Is there any free software available for layout the screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cssgrid is a part of css3 and supported by modern browsers. It’s perfect for layouts. Checkout 
display:grid

Answer (score 1):

Hi I feel like you may have come across this ones

[Editor one](https://www.bootply.com/new#)

[Edittor 2](https://www.layoutit.com/build)

the only other one that is really good is a [paid one](https://bootstrapstudio.io/), 
but if you really do not want to pay for one I recommend you use [Bootstrap Examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/) as a starting point